# FAQs Accordion Expanding Text Issue

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, accordion, padding

When I click the FAQs accordion icon to expand the answer, the answer text moves around for a split second as it adjusts and then stops.

This is an ugly bug I can't seem to figure out; I might alter the padding of the box and stop the issue but then it comes back when I add more text to the answer or change screen sizes... It just won't go away!!

It's an issue on both desktop and mobile screens.

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');

buttons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const faq = button.nextElementSibling;
    faq.classList.toggle('show');

    const icon = button.querySelector('.bi');

    if (icon.classList.contains("bi-plus")) {
      icon.classList.toggle("bi-plus");
      icon.classList.toggle("bi-dash");
    } else if (icon.classList.contains("bi-dash")) {
      icon.classList.toggle("bi-dash")
      icon.classList.toggle("bi-plus")
    }
  })
})
```

```css
.faqs-section {
  width: 86.5%;
  margin-bottom: 150px;
  position: relative;
  right: -6.5%;
}

.faqs-container {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.faqs-question {
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid #999;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-bottom: -10px;
}

.faqs-container:hover {
  color: #999;
}

.faqs-question button {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 30px 15px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-family: 'interstate', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #300600;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.6s ease-in-out;
}

.faqs-question button h3 {
  font-size: 28px;
  font-family: 'interstate', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
  padding: 10px;
}

.faqs-question button h3:hover {
  color: #999;
  transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.faqs-question i {
  font-size: 48px;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.faqs-question i:hover {
  color: #999;
  transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.faqs-question p {
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-family: 'Merriweather-Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 55px;
  color: #444;
  max-height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
}

.faqs-question p.show {
  max-height: none;
  opacity: 1;
  padding: 10px 0px 40px 15px;
  padding-right: 40px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 35px;
}
```

```html
<section class="faqs-section">
  <div class="faqs-container">
    <div class="faqs-question">
      <button>
                <h3>Which services do you provide?</h3>
                <i class="bi bi-plus"></i>
            </button>
      <p>As one of the premiere landscape architecture firms in Southern California, we offer a variety of services. From site planning, to landscape irrigation, we will ensure that all of our client needs are completely met and satisfied. We take pride
        in that fact and </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Looks like due to having different padding that happens while animation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand very well your issue, if the movement is what are you talking about, instead of setting the margins and paddings in `.show` do it in the "unshow", by default these values are 0, so the transition is affecting these values to from 0 to your `show` value.

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');

buttons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const faq = button.nextElementSibling;
    faq.classList.toggle('show');

    const icon = button.querySelector('.bi');

    if (icon.classList.contains("bi-plus")) {
      icon.classList.toggle("bi-plus");
      icon.classList.toggle("bi-dash");
    } else if (icon.classList.contains("bi-dash")) {
      icon.classList.toggle("bi-dash")
      icon.classList.toggle("bi-plus")
    }
  })
})
```

```css
.faqs-section {
  width: 86.5%;
  margin-bottom: 150px;
  position: relative;
  right: -6.5%;
}

.faqs-container {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.faqs-question {
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid #999;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-bottom: -10px;
}

.faqs-container:hover {
  color: #999;
}

.faqs-question button {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 30px 15px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-family: 'interstate', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #300600;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.6s ease-in-out;
}

.faqs-question button h3 {
  font-size: 28px;
  font-family: 'interstate', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
  padding: 10px;
}

.faqs-question button h3:hover {
  color: #999;
  transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.faqs-question i {
  font-size: 48px;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.faqs-question i:hover {
  color: #999;
  transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.faqs-question p {
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-family: 'Merriweather-Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 55px;
  color: #444;
  max-height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  padding: 10px 0px 40px 15px;
  padding-right: 40px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 35px;
}

.faqs-question p.show {
  max-height: none;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<section class="faqs-section">
  <div class="faqs-container">
    <div class="faqs-question">
      <button>
                <h3>Which services do you provide?</h3>
                <i class="bi bi-plus"></i>
            </button>
      <p>As one of the premiere landscape architecture firms in Southern California, we offer a variety of services. From site planning, to landscape irrigation, we will ensure that all of our client needs are completely met and satisfied. We take pride
        in that fact and </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```